# Open Json, replace values ​and run json.load

Tags: python, json, replace

I have an error when there is a json file, I replace the content and load it with json.load (), verify that the same json shows no error if I delete the replacement lines.

> traceback: invalid json: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

```
{
    "ope": "gen",
    "generado": "",
    "items": [{
        "unidad_de_medida": "NIU",
        "codigo": "CONS_DEL02",
        "descripcion": "[CONS_DEL02] \\"Pequeño servidor\\nraid 1, 512ECC ram",
        "cantidad": 1.000,
        "valor_unitario": 40000.00,
        "precio_unitario": 40000.00,
        "descuento": 0.00,
        "subtotal": 40000.00,
        "tipo_de_igv": 2,
        "igv": 0.00,
        "total": 40000.00,
        "anticipo_regularizacion": "false",
        "anticipo_documento_serie": "",
        "anticipo_documento_numero": "",
        "codigo_producto_sunat": "10000000"
    }, {
        "unidad_de_medida": "NIU",
        "codigo": "CONS_DEL02",
        "descripcion": "[CONS_DEL02] Pequeño servidor\\nraid 1, 512ECC ram",
        "cantidad": 1.000,
        "valor_unitario": 40000.00,
        "precio_unitario": 47200.00,
        "descuento": 0.00,
        "subtotal": 40000.00,
        "tipo_de_igv": 1,
        "igv": 7200.00,
        "total": 47200.00,
        "anticipo_regularizacion": "false",
        "anticipo_documento_serie": "",
        "anticipo_documento_numero": "",
        "codigo_producto_sunat": "10000000"
    }],
    "guias": null
}
```

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests,datetime,time,codecs,io
import json
#import bdUpdate
from glob import glob
import os
import shutil

def enviarwebservice():
    url = "https://server1/api/v1/a0307f5e9a64e26"       
    files=ls4("c:/validacionFX/","*.json") #*******ruta donde se genera el json*********    
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        if 1==1:
            for archivo in files:        
                if os.path.isfile(archivo):      
                    with io.open(archivo,'r',encoding='utf8')as file:
                        cadenaId=(os.path.basename(archivo)).split('-') #--es una tipo lista.
                        for line in file:
                            line.replace('\\"', '\"')
                        json_data=json.load(file)
                        payload=json.dumps(json_data,indent=4)

                        
def enviarwebservice():
    url = "https://server1/api/v1/a0307f5e9a64e26"           
    files=ls4("c:/validacionFX/","*.json") #*******ruta donde se genera el json*********    
    try:
        r = requests.get(url)
        if 1==1:
            for archivo in files:        
                if os.path.isfile(archivo):      
                    with codecs.open(archivo,'r',encoding='utf8')as file:
                        cadenaId=(os.path.basename(archivo)).split('-') #--es una tipo lista.        
                        json_data=json.load(file)         
                        payload=json.dumps(json_data,indent=4)
```

when I don't replace the characters, the json doesn't generate conflict.
Thanks your support.

Comment: your problem is not `replace()` which you don't even assign to variable so it changes nothing. Your problem is `for line in file` which moves pointer in file and later `json.load()` read data from the end of file. You would have to move pointer to the beginning of file using `file.seek(0)` (or reopening file).

Comment: if you want to change something then read all from file `data = file.read()`, change it `data = data.replace(...)` and then use it with `json.loads(data)` instead of using `json.load(file)`

Comment: Hi, thanks was the seek (0), but now I have an error in the \\ ", it seems that replacing does not work.

Comment: if you have new error message then create new question and you will have more space to put full error message.

Comment: you have to assign result to variable `line = line.replace('\\"', '\"')` but it will not change it inside file - It is better to read all data to variable, replace text in this string and use `loads(string)` instead of `load(file)` - see code in my previous comments